# Bouncy castle NTRU generation

Tags: java, encryption, cryptography, bouncycastle, ntruencrypt

I've faced the next problem: I don't know where to get a byte array of private key for calling correct NTRUSigningPrivateKeyParameters.

Here is my code:

```
    byte [] b = new byte[16];
    Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());

    NTRUSigningKeyGenerationParameters ntruSigningKeyGenerationParameters = NTRUSigningKeyGenerationParameters.TEST157;
    NTRUSigningPrivateKeyParameters ntruSigningPrivateKeyParameters = null;
    NTRUSigner ntruSigner = new NTRUSigner(ntruSigningKeyGenerationParameters.getSigningParameters());

    try {
        ntruSigningPrivateKeyParameters = new NTRUSigningPrivateKeyParameters(b, ntruSigningKeyGenerationParameters); // here I need to get byte array from private key
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    ntruSigner.init(true, ntruSigningPrivateKeyParameters);
    byte [] res = ntruSigner.generateSignature();
```

Does anyone had the same problem?

Comment: Is your question a) how to load a private key file into a byte array, b) how to get a private key, or c) other? Also note that you can load the private key from an InputStream; it doesn't have to be a byte array - see [javadocs](https://github.com/bcgit/bc-java/blob/master/core/src/main/java/org/bouncycastle/pqc/crypto/ntru/NTRUSigningPrivateKeyParameters.java).

Comment: @DNA a and b questions, I've seen the javadocs, but I didn't see any samples of using it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have your tried `NTRUSigningKeyPairGenerator`, and calling `getEncoded()` on the retrieved private key?

```
NTRUSigningKeyPairGenerator ntruSigningKeyPairGenerator = new NTRUSigningKeyPairGenerator();
NTRUSigningKeyGenerationParameters ntruSigningKeyGenerationParameters = NTRUSigningKeyGenerationParameters.TEST157;
ntruSigningKeyPairGenerator.init(ntruSigningKeyGenerationParameters);
AsymmetricCipherKeyPair asymmetricCipherKeyPair = ntruSigningKeyPairGenerator.generateKeyPair();
NTRUSigningPrivateKeyParameters params = (NTRUSigningPrivateKeyParameters) asymmetricCipherKeyPair.getPrivate();
System.out.println(Hex.encodeHexString(params.getEncoded()));
```

Comment: no, I haven't, but I in sources don't see anything suitable, that looks like a private key, where I can call `getEncoded()` method

Comment: On [the resulting private key](https://github.com/bcgit/bc-java/blob/master/core/src/main/java/org/bouncycastle/pqc/crypto/ntru/NTRUSigningPrivateKeyParameters.java) as already indicated.

Comment: before I can call getEncoded, first I must create a new instance. How to do it ?

Comment: NTRUSigningKeyPairGenerator ntruSigningKeyPairGenerator = new NTRUSigningKeyPairGenerator();
        AsymmetricCipherKeyPair asymmetricCipherKeyPair =  ntruSigningKeyPairGenerator.generateKeyPair();  
        asymmetricCipherKeyPair.getPrivate();  - it's not suitable for me

Comment: so where can I get the private key?

Comment: Not suitable to you? What *is* suitable for you?

Comment: I think correct object class is suitable, but not a formal wrapper, that does nothing

Comment: just type the code I gave in comment and see, that it's does no use in this situation :(

Comment: I'm so slow :D. I didn't acknowledge, that NTRUSigningPrivateKeyParameters extends AsymmetricKeyParameter. Thank you very much! Sorry my misunderstanding took a lot of your time

Comment: Never mind that, if you don't know about the init and the cast it can take a bit of puzzling. This is just 13.5 years of experience speaking :P

Comment: yep, experience is a great thing. It's a pitty, that creators of bouncycastle don't provide at least short testing samples, so that users can easily see and do all the stuff in a right way

Comment: I guess David is busy. Feel free to provide support :) I did provide some implementations already.